# How to deactivate spellcheck in p:inputTextarea PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spell-checking

I would like to deactivate the spell check in a PrimeFaces `inputTextarea`.

`spellcheck="false"` is not possible in a `p:inputTextarea`

```html
<p:inputTextarea value="#{mybean.cardescription}" 
                 cols="95"
                 autoResize="true"
                 rows="20"/>
```

Comment: use jQuery on page load `$('inputTextId').attr('spellcheck','false')`, or you should write a custom renderer for the inputTextarea.. Also I'm not sure if the [Html5RenderKit](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/renderkits/Html5RenderKit;jsessionid=JHlW9g4VIa8bligkF6W6eQix) of OmniFaces would work on PrimeFaces inputTextarea but it should be.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I don't know how to use jQuery, where should I put this code please ? In the xhtml document or in a bean ?

Answer (score 1):

**Use following:**

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript   name="/js/util/disableSpellCheck.js"/> 
</h:head>
```

---

```
$('inputTextId').attr('spellcheck','false')
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm pretty late to the party I think there is a cleaner way to do it without Javascript. When you include the namespace `xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"` you can pass attributes through to the generated HTML and you can hence directly set the attribute in your JSF code:

```xml
<p:inputTextarea value="#{mybean.cardescription}" 
        cols="95"
        pt:spellcheck="false"
        autoResize="true"
        rows="20"/>
```

This works for all HTML attributes that do not have a corresponding JSF attribute in their components.

The `pt` is selected here to avoid namespace collisions with PrimeFaces. You'll also find `p` for passthrough attributes pretty often.